# how to trigger a event on clicking dynamically created checkboxes of same group

Tags: jquery, html

Im having a 3 check boxes with same name initially, and one check box is created dynamically. If i click on any of the 3 initial checkboxes it triggers event but doesnt work on newly created one.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="NewMerheckbox" id="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="NewMerheckbox" id="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="NewMerheckbox" id="3"/>
<div id="newcheckbox">

</div>
```

and

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="NewMerheckbox"]').on('click', function() {
alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
$('#newcheckbox').html('<input type="checkbox"name="NewMerheckbox" id="4"/>');
```

Comment: Can you post a full example (HTML, JS)? The info you provided is not enough to judge the issue

Comment: I tested it here , it's worked good https://jsfiddle.net/frcte289/

Comment: Now you check why doesnt it work for the 4th elemet created [link](https://jsfiddle.net/frcte289/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add a click handler to an object that doesn't yet exist. jQuery allows you add click handlers to parent elements such that they only trigger on certain children but those children do not have to exist when the click handler is set.

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"][name="NewMerheckbox"]', function() {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

This causes the click handler to be set on `body` where it will process click events on itself and children elements. The additional argument cases the events to be filtered so that only children who match the selector trigger the handler. Since the handler is on `body`, the targeted children do not have to exist when the handler is created. You can, of course, use a more appropriate parent element. This is described in [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

hey Try This updated one  Hope It Helps You

```js
$(document).ready( function () { 
$('#newcheckbox').html('<input type="checkbox"name="NewMerheckbox" id="4"/>');
  $("input[name='NewMerheckbox']").on("click", function () {
  alert( "HeyI am calling same Function  My Id Is  " + $(this).attr('id'));
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="NewMerheckbox" id="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="NewMerheckbox" id="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="NewMerheckbox" id="3"/>
<div id="newcheckbox">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that works but triggering doesnt work on dynamically created check box